# how to create multiple filters using the standard dataTable in lwc .i passed the objects dynamically

Tags: lightning-web-components

```
@wire(getObjectInfo,'$objectName')
wiredata({data,error}){
    IF(data){
let fields = data.fields;
    }
}
```

i want to store the fields in lightning-data fields column How to do that.
Operators are (-,+ ....etc)
[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
<!----html ----!>
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Account List">
    <template if:true={isLoading}>
      <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <lightning-spinner size="large"></lightning-spinner>
      </div>

    </template>
    
    
    <template for:each={filters} for:item="filter" for:index="index">
      <div key = {filters.index} class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-gutters slds-m-around_medium">
        
        <div class="slds-col">
          <lightning-combobox 
                label="Field Name" value={filters.fieldName} 
                options={fieldOptions} onchange={handleFieldNameChange} 
                data-index={index}>
                
              </lightning-combobox>
            </div>
            
            
        <div class="slds-col">
          <lightning-combobox 
              label="Operator" value={filters.operator} 
              options={operatorOptions} onchange={handleOperatorChange} 
              data-index={index}>
          </lightning-combobox>
        </div>
      
        <div class="slds-col">
          <lightning-input 
              label="Value" value={filters.value} 
              onchange={handleValueChange} data-index={index}>
          </lightning-input>
        </div>
      
        <div class="slds-col slds-m-top_large">
          <lightning-button 
                disabled={disableRemove} label="Remove" variant="destructive" 
                onclick={removeFilter} data-index={index}>
          </lightning-button>
        </div>
      
      </div>
    </template>
  
      <br><br>
        
        
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-button 
              variant="brand" label="Search" 
              onclick={searchAccounts}>
            </lightning-button>
          
          <div class="slds-float_right">
            <lightning-button 
                variant="brand" label="Add Filter" 
                onclick={addFilter}>
            </lightning-button>
          </div>
        </div>
  </lightning-card>
        
         
  <template if:true={recordsToDisplay}>
    <lightning-card>
      <div style="height: 200px">
        <lightning-datatable 
          data={recordsToDisplay} columns={columns} sorted-by={sortBy}
          sorted-direction={sortDirection} onsort={doSorting} 
          key-field="Id" hide-checkbox-column =true 
          show-row-number-column =true onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
        </lightning-datatable>
      </div>
      <!--RECORDS PER PAGE-->
      <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-grid_align-spread" style="padding-top: 0.5em;">
        <!--RECORDS PER PAGE-->
        <div class="slds-col">
          <div class="slds-list_inline slds-p-bottom_xx-small">
              <label class="slds-text-color_weak slds-p-horizontal_x-small" for="recordsPerPage">Page Size:</label>
              <div class="slds-select_container">
                  <select class="slds-select" id="recordsPerPage" onchange={handleRecordsPerPage}>
                      <template for:each={pageSizeOptions} for:item="option">
                          <option key={option} value={option}>{option}</option>
                      </template>
                  </select>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="slds-align_absolute-center" style="height:5rem">      
          <lightning-button disabled={disableFirst} icon-name="utility:jump_to_left" label="First" class="slds-p-horizontal_x-small" alternative-text="first page" onclick={firstPage}></lightning-button>     
          <lightning-button disabled={disableFirst} icon-name="utility:chevronleft" label="Previous" alternative-text="Previous" onclick={previousPage}></lightning-button> &nbsp;     
          <span class="slds-badge">Showing {pageNumber} &nbsp;of&nbsp; {totalPages} &nbsp;&nbsp;Page(s)</span> &nbsp;     
          <lightning-button disabled={disableLast} icon-name="utility:chevronright" label="Next" alternative-text="Next" onclick={nextPage} class="slds-p-horizontal_x-small" icon-position="right"></lightning-button>     
          <lightning-button disabled={disableLast} icon-name="utility:jump_to_right" label="Last" alternative-text="last page" onclick={lastPage} icon-position="right"></lightning-button> 
        </div>
        <div class="slds-clearfix">
          <div class="slds-float_right">
              <span class="slds-badge"> Total Records: {totalRecords}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </lightning-card> 
  </template>
</template>
```

js code=>

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";
import getAccounts from "@salesforce/apex/accSrcFilter.getAccounts";
import getAccountFieldOptions from "@salesforce/apex/accSrcFilter.getAccountFieldOptions";
import { ShowToastEvent } from "lightning/platformShowToastEvent";
import Id from "@salesforce/schema/Account.Id";

const columns = [
        { label: "Account Name", fieldName: "Name", type: "text", sortable:"true" },
        { label: "Industry", fieldName: "Industry", type: "text" },
        { label: "Type", fieldName: "Type", type: "text" },
        { label: "Phone", fieldName: "Phone", type: "phone" }
        // Add more columns as needed
];

const operatorOptions = [
        { label: "Equals", value: "=" },
        { label: "Not Equals to", value: "!=" },
        { label: "less than", value: "<" },
        { label: "greater than", value: ">" },
        { label: "less or equal", value: "<=" },
        { label: "greater or equal", value: ">=" },
        { label: "Contains", value: "LIKE" },
        { label: "Starts With", value: "STARTSWITH" },
        { label: "Ends With", value: "ENDSWITH" }
];

export default class AccountList extends LightningElement {
        @track accounts;
        @track pageSizeOptions=[0, 3, 6, 9, 12];
        recordsToDisplay
        @track filters = [{ fieldName: "", operator: "", value: "" }];
        @track fieldOptions = [];
        isLoading = false;
        pageNumber = 1;
        totalPages
        totalRecords = 0;
        @track sortBy;
        @track sortDirection;
        operatorOptions = operatorOptions;
        columns = columns;


    connectedCallback() {
        getAccountFieldOptions()
        .then((data) => {
            this.fieldOptions = data;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }

    handleFieldNameChange(event) {
        const index = event.target.dataset.index;
        this.filters[index].fieldName=event.target.value; 
    }
        
    handleOperatorChange(event) {
        const index = event.target.dataset.index;
        this.filters[index].operator = event.target.value; 
        
    }
    
    handleValueChange(event) {
        
        const index = event.target.dataset.index;
        this.filters[index].value = event.target.value;
       
    }
  

    addFilter() {
        this.filters.push({ fieldName: "", operator: "", value: "" });
    }
    get disableRemove() {
        return this.filters.length === 1 ;
    }

    removeFilter() {
       // const index = event.currentTarget.dataset.index;
       let tempList = [];                 
            this.filters.forEach((record) => {                     
                let tempRec = Object.assign({}, record);                       
                tempRec.this.filters = '/' + tempRec.Id; 
                        
                tempList.push(tempRec.Id);  
            }) ;  
      
       
       this.tempList.splice(Id,1);
    
    }
    
    
    

    searchAccounts() {
        
    getAccounts({filters : this.filters})
    .then(result=>{ 
        if (result.length > 0){                 
            let tempConList = [];                 
            result.forEach((record) => {                     
                let tempConRec = Object.assign({}, record);                       
                tempConRec.AccountName = '/' + tempConRec.Id; 
                        
                tempConList.push(tempConRec);                                     
            });                 
            this.accounts = tempConList;                 
            this.totalRecords = result.length;
            this.pageSize = this.pageSizeOptions;
            this.isLoading = false;                  
            this.paginationHelper();             
        } else{ 
            this.isLoading = true;                
            const event1 = new ShowToastEvent({                     
                title: 'Error',                     
                message: 'no data found',                     
                variant: 'error'                 
            });                 
            this.dispatchEvent(event1);                 
            this.recordsToDisplay = undefined;                 
            this.pageNumber = 1; 
            this.isLoading = false;
                    
            }                     
        }).catch(error=>{  
                const event2 = new ShowToastEvent({                 
                title: 'Error',                 
                message: error.body.message,                 
                variant: 'error'             
            });             
            this.dispatchEvent(event2);             
            this.recordsToDisplay = undefined;             
            this.pageNumber = 1;
        })
    }

    doSorting(event) {
        this.sortBy = event.detail.fieldName;
        this.sortDirection = event.detail.sortDirection;
        this.sortData(this.sortBy, this.sortDirection);
    }

    
    sortData(fieldname, direction) {
        let parseData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.accounts));
        // Return the value stored in the field
        let keyValue = (a) => {
            return a[fieldname];
        };
        // cheking reverse direction
        let isReverse = direction === 'asc' ? 1: -1;
        // sorting data
        parseData.sort((x, y) => {
            x = keyValue(x) ? keyValue(x) : ''; // handling null values
            y = keyValue(y) ? keyValue(y) : '';
            // sorting values based on direction
            return isReverse * ((x > y) - (y > x));
        });
        this.accounts = parseData;
        this.paginationHelper();
    }    
    
    get disableFirst(){
        return this.pageNumber === 1;
    }
    get disableLast(){
        return this.pageNumber === this.totalPages;
    }
    

    paginationHelper(){
        this.recordsToDisplay=[];
        this.totalPages = Math.ceil(this.totalRecords / this.pageSize);
        if(this.pageNumber <= 1){
            this.pageNumber = 1;
        } else if(this.pageNumber >=this.totalPages){
            this.pageNumber = this.totalPages;
        }
        for(let i = (this.pageNumber - 1)* this.pageSize; i< this.pageNumber * this.pageSize ; i++){
            if(i === this.totalRecords) {
                break;
            }
            this.recordsToDisplay.push(this.accounts[i]);

        }

    }
    handleRecordsPerPage(event){
        this.pageSize = event.target.value;
        this.paginationHelper();
    }

    previousPage(){
        this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber -1;
        this.paginationHelper();
    }
    nextPage(){
        this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber + 1;
        this.paginationHelper();
    }
    firstPage(){
        this.pageNumber = 1;
        this.paginationHelper();
    }
    lastPage(){
        this.pageNumber = this.totalPages;
        this.paginationHelper();
    }
}
```

apex class

```
public with sharing class accSrcFilter{
    
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Account> getAccounts(List<AccountFilter> filters) {
        system.debug('filters=>'+filters);
                
            
                
                List<String> filterConditions = new List<String>();
        
                for (AccountFilter filter : filters) {
                    if (String.isNotBlank(filter.fieldName) && String.isNotBlank(filter.operator) && String.isNotBlank(filter.value)) {
                        String filOperator;
                        String filValue;
        
        
                        if (filter.operator.equals('STARTSWITH')) {
                            filOperator = 'LIKE';
                            filValue = filter.value + '%';
                        } else if (filter.operator.equals('ENDSWITH')) {
                            filOperator = 'LIKE';
                            filValue = '%' + filter.value;
                        } else if(filter.operator.equals('LIKE')){
                            // Default to 'Contains' if operator is 'LIKE' but not 'StartsWith' or 'EndsWith'
                            filOperator = 'LIKE';
                            filValue = '%' + filter.value + '%';
                        }else {
                            filOperator = filter.operator;
                            filValue = filter.value;
                        }
                        system.debug('filterValue=>'+filValue);
                        
                        filterConditions.add(filter.fieldName +' '+ filOperator +'\''+filValue+'\'');
                        system.debug('filterConditions=>'+filterConditions);
                    }
                }
        
                String query = 'SELECT Id, Name, Industry, Type, Phone FROM Account';
                if (!filterConditions.isEmpty()) {
                    query += ' WHERE ' + String.join(filterConditions, ' AND ');
                    system.debug('query=>'+query);

                }
                system.debug('ABC=>'+ Database.query(query));
                return Database.query(query);
            }
        
             
    public class AccountFilter {
        @AuraEnabled public String fieldName{get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String operator{get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public String value{get; set;}
    }
    
        



    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<FieldOption> getAccountFieldOptions() {
        List<FieldOption> fieldOptions = new List<FieldOption>();

        Schema.SObjectType accountType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
        if (accountType != null) {
            Schema.DescribeSObjectResult accountDescribe = accountType.getDescribe();
            Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldsMap = accountDescribe.fields.getMap();

            for (String fieldName : fieldsMap.keySet()) {
                Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescribe = fieldsMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe();
                fieldOptions.add(new FieldOption(fieldDescribe.getLabel(), fieldName));
            }
        }

        return fieldOptions;
    }
    public class FieldOption {
        @AuraEnabled public String label;
        @AuraEnabled public String value;

        public FieldOption(String label, String value) {
            this.label = label;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Right now, this is a _code dump_, and is of limited value. Please [edit] your answer to add a detailed explanation of how this works. That way, it can possibly help other people with similar questions.